# Is $2\pi B \coth{\frac{\pi B}{2\sqrt{A^2 - B^2}}}$ a valid lower bound for the circumference of an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, hyperbolic-functions

Suppose there is an ellipse with a semi-major axis length of $A$ and a semi-minor axis length of $B$. The task is to prove or disprove that the circumference of the ellipse in question is greater than

$$2\pi B \coth{\frac{\pi B}{2\sqrt{A^2 - B^2}}}$$

This is a problem that I received from a friend, and so far I have tried to compare it to the integral expression for the circumference of an ellipse and use Jenson's inequality to find another lower bound to compare the above expression to. This leading me to no avail, I thought I would pose the problem here to see if there is a better approach.

Comment: wow, i just looked it up.. i thought it would be something easy like π(a+b)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE (from a fellow Texan)! Please always try to include your thoughts about a question. Such information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you aren't familiar. In this case, you might say where you got this proposed lower bound; is it a textbook exercise? an online challenge? something you devised yourself? Also: are you familiar with the [formula for the exact circumference of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference)?